# Boost Log V2 + backend specific attributes?

Tags: logging, boost

I'm using Boost's Log. I have specified multiple backends and the idea is to be able to specify different filtering for each backend, meaning
ERROR logs would go to one backend, TRACE logs to the other backend, etc.
[The number of backends come from a config file, so it's not static,
I can't go for a different-formatter-per-backend approach]

My issue is that I fail to see whether I can "append" some backend specific attribute (I know there is no such thing like that) to the log records or not.

I have tried to subclass from the backends to add my own attribute to identify the backend, but it is obviously a dead end, as I can't 
forward this information to the formatter.

Any thought how this could be achieved if could be at all via Boost's Log?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have created a new synchronous sink to "inject" my extra ""attribute""
So practically my sink fill "prefilter" the log record, so in "my"
will_consume function I can access my m_LogModule attribute.

```
template< typename SinkBackendT >
class synchronous_sink_ex : public boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<SinkBackendT>
{
    public:
        synchronous_sink_ex(const std::string LogModule) : m_LogModule(LogModule) {}

        template<typename... Args>
        synchronous_sink_ex(const std::string LogModule, Args&&... args) : m_LogModule(LogModule), boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<SinkBackendT>(args...) {}

        virtual ~synchronous_sink_ex() {}

        /** This will "pre-filter" the logs based upon the logmodule */
        bool will_consume(boost::log::attribute_value_set const& attributes);

    private:
        std::string m_LogModule;
};
```